# How can i organize a list whose elements are stored in a struct?

Tags: c, sorting

Im currently working on a project (for school, yes) in which i've spent quite a few hours trying to get it to work, but now i found myself with an error that i cant seem to solve, and so i came here looking for help. The following is the code that i think is necessary, not the full code.

```
typedef struct
{
    int day, month, year;
} typeDate;

typedef struct
{
    int number;
    char name[20];
    char lastname[20];
    typeDate date_of_birth;
} typeCard;

typedef struct
{
    int associate_number;
    typeCard associates[MAX_ELEM];
} typeAssociation;

typeDate date;
typeCard card;
typeCard aux;

int get_data(typeAssociation association)
{
    association.associate_number = 0;

    int e, i;

    FILE* read = fopen("associados.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; fscanf(read, "%s %s %d %d %d %d", card.name, card.lastname, &card.number,
                    &date.day, &date.month, &date.year)
         != EOF;
         i++)
    {
        association.associate_number++;
        card.date_of_birth = date;
        association.associates[i] = card;
    }
    fclose(read);

    printf("Sort list[1/2/3]?");

    scanf("%d", &e);

    if (e == 1)
    {
       ordenar_n(&associacao);       
    }
    (...)
}

int sort_by_date(typeAssociation association)
{
    int g, m, i;

    for (i = 0; i < association.associate_number - 1; i++)
    {
        m = i;
        for (g = i + 1; g < data.year; g++)
        {
            if (date.year[g] < date.year[m])
            {
                m = g;
            }

            if (date.year[g] == date.year[m])
            {
                if (date.month[g] < date.month[m])
                {
                    m = g;
                }

                else if (date.month[g] == date.month[m])
                {
                    if (date.day[g] < date.day[m])
                    {
                        m = g;
                    }
                }
            }

            aux = association.associates[i];
            association.associates[i] = association.associates[m];
            association.associates[m] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

on another file i have (after calling the file):

```
int main(void)
{
   typeAssociation association;

   get_data(association);

}
```

The error is in the function `sort_by_date` and this function is supposed to sort a list (given by `associados.txt`) by date (stored in the struct `typeDate`) (from newest member to the oldest). I think (correct me if I'm wrong) i have the general idea going, but not the code. Can anyone help me? (it's my first post so sorry for any mistakes).

> My error is in the function sort_by_date.

Comment: The std c lib usually has a qsort function, google usually has examples

Comment: yes, i am aware that there are built in functions that sort lists, but the point isnt to use those functions :\

Comment: It looks like you're coding a Selection Sort, except you are using global variables `data` and `cartao` for some reason instead of the items in `associacao`. Can you explain how the global variables get their values and what criteria you're using to sort items, so we can help more?

Comment: `data.ano[g]` is it compiling? `ano` is an `int` member of `tipoData`

Comment: After Stargateur coment i translated the code to english (hopefully it helps, and im sorry for any spelling mistake). As for the global variables, i declared them as global because i tought it wouldnt have any negative impact in any function, it was a matter of choice (if it does matter ill put them in the get_data function). The criteria should be clearer now, i want to sort the list by date, from youngest to oldest, with values received from the file.txt. And no, the file doesnt compile, there are A LOT of errors in the function sort_by_date

Comment: @EngineerWannabe what sorting function are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RoadRunner Im trying to sort the list by date, from youngest to oldest associate

Comment: @RoadRunner with a (sketchy) selection sort

Comment: can't compile http://ideone.com/DLBI1B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass address of `typeAssociation` variable. 
Also in your code, you are comparing array elements with some global variables which is wrong.

```
int sort_by_date(typeAssociation *association)
{
    int g=0, m=0, i=0;

    for (i = 0; i < association->associate_number - 2; i++)
    {
        m = i;
        for (g = i + 1; g < association->associate_number; g++)
        {
            if (association->associates[g].date.year < association->associates[m].date.year)
            {
                m = g;
            }

            else if (association->associates[g].date.year == association->associates[m].date.year)
            {
                if (association->associates[g].date.month < association->associates[m].date.month)
                {
                    m = g;
                }

                else if (association->associates[g].date.month == association->associates[m].date.month)
                {
                    if (association->associates[g].date.day < association->associates[m].date.day)
                    {
                        m = g;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //No need to do it in i loop
        if(i != m)
        {
            aux = association.associates[i];
            association.associates[i] = association.associates[m];
            association.associates[m] = aux;
        }
    }

    return 0; //Need to return an int value.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but when i try this solution and compile, it gives me an error everytime "->" is used. How can i fix this?

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked when i switched the "->" with "." (as Joshua kindly explained, i dont need pointers since i dont want to change the original items). Now please bear with me for a second, i have some warnings saying "implicit declaration of function sort_by_date. How can i fix this? And what should i do after this question is solved?

Comment: @EngineerWannabe: If you don't need pointers, change `int sort_by_date(typeAssociation *association)` to 'int sort_by_date(typeAssociation association)'. If warning doesn't go, post the exact warning message as you see in your computer. What do you mean by what should you do after solving this question?! It is upto you!

Comment: Yes, it is done! Again thank you so much for your help. The warning message is as follows "warning: implicit declaration of function 'sort_by_date'". But am i not supposed to upvote and do some other things?

Comment: That is upto you. Anyway you have accepted the answer. That's it. Done!

Comment: Again, thank you so much. If you dont mind, could you answer me one last question? Had i used the code as you posted, with pointers, would it still work? I mean, would it change anything?

Comment: @EngineerWannabe: It will change the original `association` variable present in the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing typeAssociation by value. Your sort is not applying to the object passed in. Also, don't write your own sort. qsort is a library function.

```
int sort_by_date(typeAssociation *association)
{
    qsort(association->associates, association->associate_number, sizeof(typeCard), compare_typeCard);
}

int compare_typeCard(const void *avoid, const void *bvoid)
{
    typeCard *a = avoid;
    typeCard *b = bvoid;
    /* put your comparison code here */
}
```

And, you have the same pass-by-value mistake calling getAssociation.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to use `qsort`.

Comment: Yes, i believe that works, but im not supposed to sort it with qsort, thats why i used selection sort. And why do you use a pointer there? I've seen it while searching for other solutions to my problem but i couldnt understand why use pointers and why call structs with "->"

Comment: @EngineerWannabe When you pass something "by value", the function receives a copy of your items, which means it won't modify the original items. When you pass something "by reference", the function expects a pointer to the original location of the items, and you use `->` instead of `.` with a pointer to a member of a struct like `ano`. That will allow you to modify the original items.

Comment: You know what, I'm going to leave this. One step at a time. I'm not going to rewrite 50 lines of code to show how to use pointers when 1 will do.

Comment: Ah, i think i understand. But in this case i dont want to modify the original items, thus i dont use "->" right?